# ¿Cómo se acceder a los data.frame almacenados en una lista?

Tags: r

Mi pregunta es ¿Cómo se trabaja con las variables, si mis datos están en modo de lista data.frame?

```
Length Class      Mode
 [1,] 1      data.frame list
 [2,] 1      data.frame list
 [3,] 1      data.frame list
 [4,] 1      data.frame list
 [5,] 1      data.frame list
 [6,] 1      data.frame list
 [7,] 1      data.frame list
 [8,] 1      data.frame list
```

**Nota:** Cuando intento solicitar los nombres de mis variables no puedo conocerlos, pero necesito el modo list para trabajar con todos mis archivos de variables iguales.

```
dir()
files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

myfiles = lapply(files, read.delim)

summary(myfiles)

myfiles

names(myfiles)

hist(myfiles)

do.call_rbind_read.csv <- function(path, pattern = "*.csv") {
  files = list.files(path, pattern, full.names = TRUE)
  do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) read.csv(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)))
}

myfiles

names(myfiles)# > names(myfiles)#NULL

str(myfiles)

summary (myfiles, n =1)

is.list(data.frame(myfiles))
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema de no tener un nombre para cada elemento de la lista puedes resolverlo con R base de la siguiente forma:

```
names(myfiles) <- sub(".csv", "", files)
```

Simplemente asignamos el nombre de cada archivo sin la extensión como nombre de cada  elemento de la lista, también podrías usar un vector en particular para establecer los nombres.

No esta de más mencionar que puede ser muy útil trabajar con la funcionalidad más moderna para la manipulación de datos como `dplyr`, `magrittr`, `purr` o directamente usando el metapaquete `tidyverse`. Te va a permitir hacer cosas como estas:

```
library(tidyverse)

files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")

# Generamos una lista de data.frame con nombre
#
files %>%                       # Con la lista de archivos CSV
    map(read.csv) %>%           # leemos cada uno
    set_names(                  # Configuramos el nombre de cada elemento
        sub(".csv", "", files)       
        ) ->  myfiles           # Asignamos la lista a myfiles
```

O incluso, si quisieras todas las listas en un único `data.frame`

```
# Leemos todos los CSV y generamos un único data.frame
#
files %>%                       # Con la lista de archivos CSV
    map(read.csv) %>%           # leemos cada uno
    reduce(rbind) -> df         # los combinamos todos en un único df
```

Comment: Si se cumplen determinadas condiciones (igual número de columnas en c/ data.frame de la lista, iguales nombres de columna) se puede usar `purrr::map_df()` que hace el `map-reduce`  en un sólo paso.